# How do I go about installing a certificate on a nanoserver-1709 based image on a docker container?

Tags: asp.net, docker, docker-compose, nano-server

I've been looking around this image for any cert managers but I can't find anything that will help me install a .cer certificate. The 1709 nanoserver image doesn't come with powershell so in order to use that I would have to do a multi-staged build with the microsoft/windowsservercore image but I'm not quite sure how I'd go about doing this, I can't seem to find anything through google that will help.

If anybody knows a way to install the cert with or withour a multi-stage build that would be very appreciated.

For those interested, here's my docker-compose.yml and Dockerfile

## docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  myapp:
    image: myapp
    ports:
    - "5000:80"
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: MyApp\Dockerfile
    container_name: "myapp"
    hostname: "myapp"
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: "microsoft/mssql-server-windows-express"
    environment:
      SA_PASSWORD: ""
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
    container_name: "myapp"
    hostname: "myapp"
```

## Dockerfile

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0-nanoserver-1709 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0-nanoserver-1709 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY MyApp.sln ./
COPY MyApp/MyApp.csproj MyApp/
RUN dotnet restore -nowarn:msb3202,nu1503
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/MyApp
RUN dotnet restore
RUN dotnet ef database update
RUN dotnet build -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyApp.dll"]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On some images, there is a tool called `certoc.exe` that allows you to import a certificate (usage: `certoc.exe -addstore root my_root_certificate.cer`).
This tool is not present on the 1709 images, but is present on images such as `microsoft/nanoserver:sac2016`.

To sum-up, the best way I found to deal with that is to change the `Dockerfile` to contain something like:

`FROM microsoft/nanoserver:sac2016 as tool
COPY --from=tool /Windows/System32/certoc.exe .
USER ContainerAdministrator
RUN certoc.exe -addstore root my_root_certificate.cer`

Complete example available here: https://pvlerick.github.io/2018/11/how-to-run-an-https-asp.net-core-app-using-test-certificates-in-nanoserver-1709-1803-with-docker

A huge thanks to Joshua Chini here: https://joshuachini.com/2018/02/08/how-to-import-an-enterprise-certificate-into-a-windows-container/

Comment: I think the sac2016 image is gone now, but if the host has certoc you can copy it from `C:/Windows/system32/certoc.exe` next to the Dockerfile then do `COPY ./certoc.exe ./`

Comment: It's cool idea to copy, but it's impossible to do this trick on 1809:
`C:\>docker run --rm -it mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:sac2016 cmd
Pulling from windows/nanoserver
bce2fbc256ea: Pull complete
6f2071dcd729: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:2b783310e6c82de737e893abd53ae238ca56b5a96e2861558fb9a111d6691ddb
docker: Error response from daemon: CreateComputeSystem: The container operating system does not match the host operating system.C:>ver
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.1457]`

Comment: certoc.exe isn't part of the 8.0.101-nanoserver-ltsc2022 docker image.